# is it possible to create crontab that runs every 5 hours 30 minutes

Tags: linux, cron

I have to schedule execution of a .sh file for every 5 hours 30 minutes. is it possible to configure this way in linux crontab.

Comment: 30 */5 * * * will this work ?

Comment: so is there any possibility to do this using crontab ?

Comment: i am now clear that (30 */5 * * * ) will run the job at 5:30, 10:30, 15:30, 20:30 in a day. Correct me if am wrong . but am not getting an idea how to schedule a crontab to run for every 5 hours 30 mins. thats the issue.

Comment: Am not sure who is down voting this question. i think its better they can ignore if they don't have a answer or a explanation.

Comment: can some one help to get a answer for this question !

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Also make sure your shell script should have valid permissions to exeucte.

30 */5 * * * sh yourscript